# Unity: Generic Method to get or add a component

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

Every time I make a new Script in Unity, I always end up doing a bunch of checks for any components my script depends on, like:

```
SpriteRenderer sr = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

if(sr == null)
      sr = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>() as SpriteRenderer;
```

So I decided to play around and make a generic method to do this with any Component, and I came up with the following code, which I simply added right to my own new Script.

```
  T GetOrAddComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        T component = gameObject.GetComponent<T>();

        if (component == null)     
            component = gameObject.AddComponent<T>() as T;

        return component;

    }
```

I've tried it and the function works well, but I'm wondering if there is any major downside to this approach, or if there is some other better way to complete the same task, possibly using a existing method I am unaware of or by creating the method in some other way.

Comment: Do it in start/awake and there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: May I suggest `return o.Get<T>() ?? o.Add<T>()` (pretty sure `as T` is redundant)

Comment: This is all extremely anti-pattern for an ECS game engine.

Answer (score 2):

The GetComponent method is actually rather taxing on the system. If you are developing for mobile, too many of them can cause a noticeable lag in load times.

I personally use RequireComponent method. Then the script would automatically add the component the moment it's added to the GameObject. Then I would manually drag the name of the component to the field on the script object in the inspector.

Example:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

// PlayerScript requires the GameObject to have a RigidBody component
[RequireComponent (typeof (RigidBody))]
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehavior {
    [SerializeField]
    private RigidBody rb;
...
}
```

Comment: I've never really made use of the Requirecomponent method, but you've outlined the advantages nicely.  After using it I could simply make the single GetComponent call and it would be guaranteed it will find the Component, so there would be no need for any checks or calls to AddComponent.

Answer (score 1):

First i recommend you to use "RequireComponent" :

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(AnotherComponent))]
public class NetworkService : MonoBehaviour
{ 
   private SpriteRenderer _sRenderer;

   //strong way to never get a null reference.
   #if UNITY_EDITOR
   private void OnValidate()
   {
       if (null == _sRenderer)
           _sRenderer = GetComponent<_sRenderer>();
   }

   #endif
```

the "OnValidate" [method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html)  will be executed every time you make a change in the value of a parameter in the editor or load the script/component.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static void GetOrAddComponent<T>(this GameObject model, Action<T> onSucess) where T: Component {
    onSucess(model.GetComponent<T>() ?? model.AddComponent<T> () as T);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example with the callback ?

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Unity (With C# 8.0 and above) you can simply do this in one line.

```
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
public SpriteRenderer GetSpriteRenderer => spriteRenderer ??= GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>() ?? gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

The code above does three things.

- Returns private local spriteRenderer component from the getter property if it's not null.
- If spriteRenderer is null, then it proceed to assign the value by calling GetComponent() before returning.
- If GetComponent() returns null, then the next operation will add sprite renderer component to the game object and assign to spriteRenderer before returning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using an extension method:

```cs
    public static class MonoBehaviourGetOrAddComponent {
        public static T GetOrAddComponent<T>(this GameObject self) where T : Component
        {
            T component = self.GetComponent<T>();
            return component != null
                ? component : self.AddComponent<T>() as T; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I now realise that when trying to implement this, what you probably really want is to use [`RequireComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) as pointed [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160936/439034). `RequireComponent` makes sure that the component is added to the gameObject if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Many people here have pointed out the `[RequireComponent()]` attribute, which is a fair point, but I believe there are cases where it is not enough at all. This attribute is very useful if you deal with an object that is supposed to change only a little if not at all. Moreover, this attribute implies that a specific component should **always**  be attached alongside a given Monobehavior. In practice, it's a big constraint. If you really try to separate components from each other, you'll meet situations where adding and removing components is necessary.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in methods that allows to *"Add Or Get"* component. Though this should not be very hard to achieve :

```cs
public static T AddOrGetComponent<T>(this GameObject gameObject) where T : Component
{
    return gameObject.TryGetComponent<T>(out var outComponent)
        ? outComponent
        : gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
}
```

As others have pointed out, `GetComponent<T>()` is an expensive operation so you should use it carefully anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it all in one if statement if you'd like:

```
SpriteRenderer sr;

if(gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>())
    sr = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
else
    sr = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>() as SpriteRenderer;
```

You will potentially be making the `GetComponent` call twice, but if you like the code structure better so be it. I personally think the way you are doing it is best though.

Though to be even more concise, you can return the component directly instead of having to store it in the variable `component`

```
public T GetOrAddComponent<T>() where T : Component
{
    if (gameObject.GetComponent<T>())
        return gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
    else     
        return gameObject.AddComponent<T>() as T;
}
```

And as long as you are doing this at scene load or in the `start` function, there really won't be any performance difference.

Comment: Why would you recommend the double call of GetComponent while the OP has a single call?

Comment: It might not have answered the question very well, but it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @XanderLuciano it is a different approach indeed but the problem here is that it favours fewer lines of code over performance which is generally bad practice since code readability is clearly not an issue.